# FileSystemWatcher is firing twice and program stops abruptly

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, filesystemwatcher

i want to use filesystem watcher and display the changed information on a form when the file is changed but onchaged event is fired but it is fired two times instead of once and the form that i want to display is never shown and the program stops without showing any exceptions it just stops debugging

```
public void Run()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = pathOfPatientFixedFile.Remove(pathOfPatientFixedFile.IndexOf("PatientFixedData.xml")-1);
    watcher.Filter = "PatientFixedData.xml";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GetPatientInfo(e.FullPath);
        frmPatientInfoDisplay displayPatientInfo = new frmPatientInfoDisplay(_patientInfo);
        displayPatientInfo.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

code for GetPatientInfo

```
private void GetPatientInfo(String filePath)
{
    try
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (line.IndexOf("<IsPatientFixed>") > 0)
            {
                var value = GetTagValue(line, "<IsPatientFixed>", "</IsPatientFixed>");
                if (value == "true" || value == "True")
                {
                    if (line.IndexOf("<PatientID>") > 0)
                        _patientInfo[0] = GetTagValue(line, "<PatientID>", "</PatientID>");
                    if (line.IndexOf("<PatientName>") > 0)
                        _patientInfo[1] = GetTagValue(line, "<PatientName>", "</PatientName>");
                    if (line.IndexOf("<PatientSex>") > 0)
                        _patientInfo[2] = GetTagValue(line, "<PatientSex>", "</PatientSex>");
                    if (line.IndexOf("<PatientDateOfBirth>") > 0)
                        _patientInfo[3] = GetTagValue(line, "<PatientDateOfBirth>", "<PatientDateOfBirth>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `GetPatientInfo()` look like?

Comment: you could implement your TODO! Print out the exception info (message and stacktrace) to gather more information of what happened!

Comment: if you place a breakpoint in the event, up to where can you debug until the debugger "just stops"?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz i did it does not enters catch blocks it does'nt throws any exception

Comment: @mtijn i did that it enters instantiates the frmPatientInfoDisplay form enters there assigns value to the text box but not all of them leaves the form,then the event gets fired again it again enters frmPatientInfoDisplay form and then stops

Comment: ok what is `frmPatientInfoDisplay`, and what does its constructor look like? and `pathOfPatientFixedFile.Remove(pathOfPatientFixedFile.IndexOf("PatientFixedData.xml")-1);` could potentially throww an uncaught exception, and try enabling "break on all exceptions" and then see if the debugger still "just stops".

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you're misusing the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) since it's a disposable component - it ought to be stored in a field, not a local variable, and disposed when no longer required.

Because you're not storing a long lived reference, it *may* be being garbage collected, and that *may* be leading to debugging stopping.

Also, it may fire multiple times, depending on what operations are being performed on the files by whichever other programs are interacting with the file - and there's no guarantee that the file will be accessible to *your* program at the point at which you receive notification.

As eluded to in the comments, you really need to a) Implement your TODOs, or b) Remove these empty `catch` blocks (the better option, IMO). You say "no exception is thrown", but you're making that pretty difficult to detect at the moment. It would be far better to let the program crash with a nice ugly error.